# syntax error: unexpected end of file while executing a query inside while block

Tags: bash, unix

I have prepared a shell script which takes 6 char(s) from a file and insert a particular record using sql insert query within a while loop(as the number of records in file is huge).

Upon running the script I am receiving below error - 
./TestScriptFor.sh: line 40: syntax error: unexpected end of file

```
#!/bin/bash

varSIAREQUESTID=$1
varCINAME=$2
#varWORDLENGTH=$3
#DB connection parameter


DBUSER='#USERNAME#'
DBUSERPASSWORD='#PWD#'
DB='oracle'
MYDB='#CONNECTIONSTRING#'

OLDIFS=$IFS

# while loop
while IFS= read -r -n6 LOCATIONID
do
    #insert into database 
    sqlplus -s ${DBUSER}/${DBUSERPASSWORD}@${MYDB} <<EOT
    set linesize 32767
    set feedback off
    set heading off
    insert into nbn_sia_locationids (siarequestid,locationid,ciname) values('$varSIAREQUESTID','$LOCATIONID','$CINAME');
    exit
EOT
        echo  "$LOCATIONID"


    # display one character at a time

done < TestData.csv
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Comment: Is your `TestData.csv` copied from a Windows machine? Have you ensure it doesn't have DOS CRLF endings?

Comment: No. It has been created within UNIX machine and anyways I have converted them to unix compatible using dos2unix command.

Comment: would you mind providing sample data from your CSV ?

Comment: You've only pasted 33 lines and haven't actually included the end of the script (Line 40). For questions like this, you're better off using http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @PS. ASD001ASD002 is the data I am using in the file.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan what is the syntax for end of the script?

Comment: Make sure then is a newline at end-of-file.  If in doubt just add a blank line onto the end.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses.

I did below two steps to resolved the issue - 
1. dos2unix TestData.csv - although I had created this file in UNIX itself but did this as well.
2. a new line at the end of the file as suggested by @cdark

regards,
dhananjay